# Как сделать фильтрацию на сайте Django?

Tags: python, html, django

Есть модель Engine:

```
class Engine(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Название')
    capacity_per_hour = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Ёмкость (А/ч)')
    CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'Обратная'),
        ('2', 'Прямая'),
    )
    AUTO = (
        ('1', 'Audi'),
        ('2', 'BMW'),
        ('3', 'Ford'),
        ('4', 'Honda'),
        ('5', 'Hyndai'),
        ('6', 'Kia'),
        ('7', 'Lada'),
        ('8', 'Mazda'),
        ('9', 'Mercedes-Benz'),
        ('10', 'Mitsubishi'),
        ('11', 'Nissan'),
        ('12', 'Renault'),
        ('13', 'Skoda'),
        ('14', 'Toyota'),
        ('15', 'Volkswagen')
    )
    # Availability
    AVAILABILITY = (
        ('1', 'В наличии'),
        ('2', 'Нет в наличии')
    )
    polarity = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=CHOICES, verbose_name='Полярность')
    starting_current_ampers = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Пусковой ток (А)')
    dimensions_length_mm = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Длинна')
    dimensions_width_mm = models.IntegerField(default=175, verbose_name='Ширина')
    dimensions_height_mm = models.IntegerField(default=190, verbose_name="Высота")
    guarantee_month = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Гарантия (месяцев)')
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Цена')
    price_2 = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Цена при обмене')
    description = models.TextField(default=f'Аккумуляторы НАЗВАНИЕ - это аккумуляторы эконом класса с рациональным соотношением цены, емкости и стартерного тока. Производтся на мощностях Курского аккумуляторного завода - крупнейшего в России и СНГ предприятия по производству химических источников тока. Аккумуляторная батарея НАЗВАНИЕ сконструтирована таким образом, чтобы обеспечить эксплутационную надежность по привлекательной цене.', verbose_name='Описание')
    car = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=AUTO, verbose_name='Авто, к которому подходит акб', default='Нет авто')
    availability = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Наличие', choices=AVAILABILITY, default='1')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

И мне нужно сделать фильтрацию этих самых аккумуляторов. Приведу пример:
Есть машина audi, у неё объём двигателя - 1.6л, для таких двигателей подходит акб от 45А/ч до 60А/ч. и так далее, мне нужно чтобы на странице выводились все акб от 45 до 60 а/ч, и так далее, как это можно сделать?